# iOS: Cast result of coredata fetch to array and passing to another class

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

in my class I have a method to extract data from coredata. But I have a problem: I need to convert the result to an array, because then I'll have to use that array in an other class.

The method is:

```
    func loadQuestion() -> NSArray{
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Questions> = Questions.fetchRequest()

        do {
            let array = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest) as NSArray
            guard array.count > 0 else { print("[EHY!] Non ci sono elementi da leggere "); return array }

            return array
        } catch let errore {
            print("error FetchRequest")
        }

        return list 
    }
```

I can't figure out how to convert the variable array?

The result (wrong)

[image]

> Edit: I write this because I want to convert the result of fetch into
>   an array, so you can switch to another class

Comment: @TusharSharma I defined in another class an array like: `var array: NSArray = []` because I want to pass the array from the class where I `loadQuestion ()` function to another class.

Comment: Then I wrote (in the class in which I want the array) `array = loadQuestion () CoreDataController. shared` 
 to get that array and then `print (array)` to print the contents. The problem is that it doesn't print the exact data, but memories and errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Core Data: Convert result of fetch request to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686273/ios-core-data-convert-result-of-fetch-request-to-an-array)

Comment: @Sneak no. What should I do I is different; I've seen that discussion.

Comment: Explain why it is different instead of saying that it is different. You have many threads about the same topic, I just took the first one for your duplicate. Did you look through the rest? IF you did , update your question with what threads you already looked at and why it differs from yours and not work out for you.

Comment: Not getting you are you getting any error in above method.? I guess you are trying to  return  array from this function and get values in another class?

Comment: @TusharSharma Yes, I want to return an array from this method and use it in another class. I edited the post and I added a picture, what print (array) I print to the console. aren't the data in coredata, I don't understand what is wrong

Comment: You have added a screenshot with an error text. You are probably just inserting the entire result as ONE object into the array, instead of looping through the results and adding them one by according to what you need. Again, read the duplicate questions and you will see how it is done. You can see another duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524510/swift-fetch-coredata-as-array . Like I said, if you think that there is **something different** in the duplicates I have linked, you need to specify **why it is different from your case** . Which you still havent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch` *returns* an (optional) array, so all you need to do is return that from your function.  Since `fetch` `throws` your function should either `throw` or at least return an optional, as the fetch can fail.

In Swift it is very rarely necessary to use `NSArray`; a properly typed Swift array will make your code clearer and safer. Since CoreData in Swift supports Generics, `fetch` will return the appropriate array type automatically, based on your `NSFetchRequest`.  Even if you are calling this function from Objective-C, it is best to let the compiler bridge the Swift array to an `NSArray` for you

Finally, you are using `guard` incorrectly; you attempt to return `array` in the case where it has 0 items,  otherwise you return some variable `list` which isn't declared in the code you have shown.

```
func loadQuestion() -> [Questions]? {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Questions> = Questions.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let array = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest) as [Questions]
        return array
    } catch let errore {
        print("error FetchRequest \(errore)")
    }

    return nil 
}
```